# Why this transform is not equivalent?

Tags: javascript

I have a script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userName').blur(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'GetUserServlet',
            data : {
                userName : $('#userName').val()
            },
            success : function(responseText) {
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I have made it easier by this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userName').blur( getAjax() );
});

function getAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'GetUserServlet',
        data : {
            userName : $('#userName').val()
        },
        success : function(responseText) {
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);
        }
    });
};
```

The resulting code does not work. Why this transform is not equivalent?

Comment: because you're calling `getAjax()` instantly. instead use this: `$('#userName').blur( getAjax );`

Comment: `getAjax === function() {...}` whereas `getAjax() === undefined` (i.e. the return value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `getAjax()` instead of passing it as a function reference. Since `getAjax()` does not return any value, you are actually calling:

```
$('#userName').blur( undefined );
```

To fix this, just pass the reference:

```
$('#userName').blur( getAjax );
```